Executor в aiogram не устанавливается
В PyCharm установил aiogram, при "from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types" подчеркивает executor, попробовал pip install aiogram[utils], но не помогло

установите aiogram 2.x

В Aiogram v3 больше нет executor. Скорее всего, вы смотрите старое видео на youtube или старую статью, где рассказывали про версию v2.
